# Android studio не видит смартфон

Tags: android, android-sdk

Android studio не видит телефон. Подключаю через USB, режим разработчика и отладка по USB включены. Драйвера вроде бы устанавливались при подключении к ПК телефона.

И может можно просто как-то устанавливать сразу приложение на телефон? Делать установочный пакет, таким образом тоже можно тестировать, медленней но можно. Только как это сделать?

Comment: Проверить, видно ли устройство, можно используя утилиту `adb` из Android SDK (искать в `sdk\platform-tools`). Для этого её нужно запустить из консоли с параметром devices: `adb.exe devices`. В результате отобразится список устройств, видимых с компьютера. Если список пуст, значит есть какая-то проблема (драйвер/и т.п.).

Comment: Можно собрать приложение (`Build` -> `Generate Signed APK`) и просто перетащить его на устройство (предварительно открыть в проводнике папку устройства). Далее остаётся установить этот файл на самом устройстве.

Comment: http://digphone.ru/esli-android-adb-ne-vidit-smartfon/ посмотри вот тут, иногда помогает

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если на телефоне стоит root то можно отлаживаться по wify установив это приложение: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=ru

Почему IDE может не видеть телефон?

1) установлены не те драйвера

2) слишком длинный/поврежденый кабель или разъем. При этом зарядка будет идти, и комп будет видить, но подключиться из IDE не получится.

3) кто-то блокирует девайс. Например под Linux см, http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: У меня Win, проблема не в кабеле, проблема в драйверах. Их непонятно где искать.
Root на телефоне не стоит, стремно лезть туда, еще что-то не так сделаю и вообще телефон сломаю.

Comment: Ищите драйвера, если девайс китайский, часто это безнадега, для разработки непригоден.

Comment: @АлександрЛазневой попробуйте универсальный метод: зайти в Windows в список устройств, найти там неопознанное устройство, и в своствах найти Dev_id, вот примерная инструкция: http://www.howtogeek.com/193798/how-to-find-drivers-for-unknown-devices-in-the-device-manager/

Comment: Спасибо, попробую так.

Answer (score 1):

**Включите Режим Разработчика на вашем телефоне**

Для этого:

> 1. Сначала выберите Главное меню и откройте Настройки.
> 2. После этого перейдите в Об устройстве.
> 3. Теперь найдите и нажмите Информация о программном обеспечении.
> 4. Чтобы включить режим разработчика, несколько раз нажмите на номер сборки.

Теперь для вас доступны Developer options. Перейдите туда и включите USB debugging.
Все должно заработать!

Answer (score 0):

Без всяких танцев с бубнами, за 5 минут законнектился и на стареньком Самсунге уже запустился проект.

Олег писал так:
*Как правило, мучения со стандартным набором драйверов часто ни к чему не приведут, поэтому рекомендую сразу качать вот этот файл (не боись - это не вирус, хоть антивирус и ругается) и, предварительно удалив старые драйвера, установить этот файл (во время установки телефон лучше не подключать).

После установки драйверов, подключите по USB свой аппарат к компьютеру. Все нужные настройки запустятся и автоматически установятся.
Далее запускаем Android Studio. Идем в Tools --- Android и ставим галочку напротив строки "Enable ADB Integration" (ADB - Android Debug Bridge). После этого нужно настроить Android Studio так, чтобы при нажатии на зеленую кнопочку "Run" ваше приложение сразу устанавливалось и запускалось на подключенном смартфоне...*

[Взято отсюда](http://learn-android.ru/publ/podkljuchenie_fizicheskogo_ustrojstva_k_android_studio/1-1-0-1.html?p=http://developeroleg.ucoz.ru/Files/PdaNetA4150.exe)
Файл для скачивания брать там же, но пока не знаю, можно ли и как вставлять здесь файлы.